# Send email button in custom post type backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added a button in the backend of my custom post type editor.

I want to send an email using `wp_mail()` when admin user click a button.

I've added this custom form and button to a meta box. See screenshot.

The problem is that when clicking this button Wordpress redirects to the default backend posts list page (https://mysite.test/wp-admin/edit.php).

I am making use of the `do_action( "admin_post_{$action}" )` hook.

When I inspect the page I see Wordpress has removed the tags.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $quote_add_meta_nonce = wp_create_nonce('send_quote_email_form_nonce');

    add_action('admin_post_quote_email_pdf', 'quote_email_pdf');

    function quote_email_pdf()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['send_quote_email_meta_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['send_quote_email_meta_nonce'], 'send_quote_email_form_nonce')) {
            $emailMessage = '<h1>It works</h1>';
            echo $emailMessage;
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="quote_email_pdf">
    <input type="hidden" name="send_quote_email_meta_nonce" value="<?php echo $quote_add_meta_nonce ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Email quote to customer" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: _"The problem is that when clicking this button Wordpress redirects to the default backend posts list page (`https://mysite.test/wp-admin/edit.php`)."_ - well that appears to be the form action you specified with `action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>"`, so what about that surprises you now?

Comment: If you want to stay on the editing page you are currently on, then it would make much more sense to make an AJAX request to send this data to the server, than to actually submit a form.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. Your first comment pointed out a mistake from my part. It looks like I need to append the action `action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>?action=quote_email_pdf"` like this.

Comment: @CBroe as for your second comment, I've read an article that AJAX is not recommended to send an email.  I'm trying to look for it in my history in the meantime. If the above action does not work, I'll try the AJAX method.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I went with AJAX and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, AJAX solved the problem.

Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_quote_email_pdf', 'quote_email_pdf');

function quote_email_pdf()
{
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

    die();
}
?>
<button class="button" id="downloadQuote">Send email</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  const fullName = $('#quoteFullName').text();
  const emailAddress = $('#quoteEmail a').text();

  $('#downloadQuote').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: sf_admin_ajax.sf_admin_ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          action: 'quote_email_pdf',
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          fullName: fullName
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('.preloader-window').addClass('active')
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
          $('.preloader-window').removeClass('active')
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function ( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
          $('.preloader-window').removeClass('active')
          console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    })

  })
});
</script>
```